# Use of Thread.currentThread().join() in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, jersey-2.0

The following code is taken from an example in the Jersey project. See [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.22.1/examples/helloworld/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/helloworld/App.java).

```
public class App {

    private static final URI BASE_URI = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/base/");
    public static final String ROOT_PATH = "helloworld";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("\"Hello World\" Jersey Example App");

            final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldResource.class);
            final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, resourceConfig, false);
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    server.shutdownNow();
                }
            }));
            server.start();

            System.out.println(String.format("Application started.\nTry out %s%s\nStop the application using CTRL+C",
                    BASE_URI, ROOT_PATH));

            //////////////////////////////
            Thread.currentThread().join();
            //////////////////////////////

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            //
        }

    }
}
```

I understand what is going on apart from the use of `Thread.currentThread().join();`.

I'm a Java newbie and my understanding is that this will block the execution of the current thread (in this case, the main thread), and effectively deadlock it. i.e. it will cause the current (main) thread to block until the current (main) thread finishes, which will never happen.

Is this correct? If so, why is it there?

Comment: from the log message you see that the server is started and the main thread will wait until a signal for interrupt is not received,

Comment: `Use of Thread.currentThread().join()` is completely, utterly, and entirely meaningless, and a bug. Remove.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Thread.currentThread().join()` blocks the current thread forever. In your example, that prevents the `main` from exiting, unless the program is killed, e.g. with CTRL+C on Windows.

Without that line, the main method would exit right after the server is started.

An alternative would have been to use `Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);`.

Comment: Or make the background thread it is "waiting" non-daemon threads.

Comment: So CTRL+C causes the shutdown hook to be invoked on another thread, which shuts down the server, and then the program terminates?  Without the main thread ever running to completion?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Indeed - in this case I suspect the thread is a daemon thread and you can't change that - but I don't know this specific library.

Answer (score 10):

It's a common misunderstanding that if the `main` thread exits, the program will exit.

This is only true if there is no non-daemon thread running.  This may be true here, but usually it is better IMHO to make the background threads this main is "waiting" for non-dameon and let the main thread exit when it doesn't have anything to do.  I have see developers put `Thread.sleep()` wrapped in an infinite loop. etc.